# pytest distributed testing xdist by class

Tags: python, testing, pytest, xdist

Currently I am running tests as follows:

```
py.test test.py -s -v -d --tx 3*popen
```

which distributes all the pytest test functions we have among 3 python processes.

```
class TestClass():
    def test_1():
        pass
    def test_2():
        pass
    def test_3():
        pass
```

I want xdist/pytest to distribute the jobs by class:

```
class TestClass1():
    def test_1():
        pass
class TestClass2():
    def test_2():
        pass
class TestClass3():
    def test_3():
        pass
```

Is there a flag I can pass pytest/xdist to do this?

Comment: It's currently impossible to change the granularity of test distribution. But this a feature a lot of people want (including me!). There's an open issue here: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/18

Comment: You can use `--dist=loadscope` as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56475200/15353043).