# Run multiple pytest file parallelly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-xdist

In my parent folder there is a subfolder tests and all pytest files are inside these. For example

..../tests/test_abc.py
.../tests/test_xyz.py

There are about 8 to 10 test cases in each of the pytest files. I want to run both these files parallelly as executing one after another it's taking a lot of time, to execute 20 cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run pytest tests in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733763/how-to-run-pytest-tests-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2):

You specifically want to use the `--dist=loadfile` arg of `pytest-xdist` in order to split tests in parallel via file. From [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/2.5.0/): `Tests are grouped by their containing file. Groups are distributed to available workers as whole units. This guarantees that all tests in a file run in the same worker.`

So you would first `pip install pytest-xdist`, and then run your tests like this:

```bash
pytest -n2 --dist=loadfile
```