# How to scrap many url's from a single website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

The code below navigates from page 1 up to the end, but what if there are many, like 10,000? Could there be another approach or should I just stick to this one?

Also in the case where a page is not clickable, after 3 retries I would wish to skip that page and go to the next page.

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15"
]

driver_path = '/users/tosh/downloads/chromedriver'
user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options)

main_url = 'https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/Chome/pencarian/'
driver.get(main_url)
time.sleep(5)

href_set = set()
page = 1
max_retries = 3

search_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type="submit"]')
search_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

while True:
    for _ in range(max_retries + 1):
        try:
            section = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="pageload"]')
            elements = section.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="list-group-item"]/a[contains(., "Lihat")]')
            if not elements:
                break

            for element in elements:
                href = element.get_attribute('href')
                href_set.add(href)

            href_list = list(href_set)
            href_list = [href.replace('/Chome/', '/chome/') for href in href_list]
            with open('hrefs.txt', 'w') as file:
                for href in href_list:
                    file.write(href + '\n')

            next_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//ul[@class="pagination pull-left"]/li/a[text()="{page + 1}"]')
            next_page_link.click()
            time.sleep(5)

            page += 1
            break
        except (WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
            if _ < max_retries:
                print(f"Retrying page {page}, Attempt {_ + 1}")
                continue
            else:
                print(f"Unable to navigate to page {page} after {max_retries} attempts")
                break

href_list = list(href_set)
href_list = [href.replace('/Chome/', '/chome/') for href in href_list]
with open('hrefs.txt', 'w') as file:
    for href in href_list:
        file.write(href + '\n')

driver.quit()
```

This part navigates to pages 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on. But this might take days to finish over 10,000 pages. The website has no API. Please advice me if there is a better approach than mine.

```
while True:
    for _ in range(max_retries + 1):
        try:
            section = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="pageload"]')
            elements = section.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="list-group-item"]/a[contains(., "Lihat")]')
            if not elements:
                break

            for element in elements:
                href = element.get_attribute('href')
                href_set.add(href)

            href_list = list(href_set)
            href_list = [href.replace('/Chome/', '/chome/') for href in href_list]
            with open('hrefs.txt', 'w') as file:
                for href in href_list:
                    file.write(href + '\n')

            next_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//ul[@class="pagination pull-left"]/li/a[text()="{page + 1}"]')
            next_page_link.click()
            time.sleep(5)

            page += 1
            break
        except (WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
            if _ < max_retries:
                print(f"Retrying page {page}, Attempt {_ + 1}")
                continue
            else:
                print(f"Unable to navigate to page {page} after {max_retries} attempts")
                break

href_list = list(href_set)
href_list = [href.replace('/Chome/', '/chome/') for href in href_list]
with open('hrefs.txt', 'w') as file:
    for href in href_list:
        file.write(href + '\n')
```

Comment: Web sites generally do not want you to scrape them. They especially do not want you to scrape them rapidly since this typically damages the site's ability to serve other users.

Comment: yes i know but, please if you can, run the code and see my point. am trying to speed up the process.

Comment: yes i know but, please if you can, run the code and see my point. am trying to speed up the process.

Answer (score 2):

My advice here is not to use selenium.

Selenium is excellent and I use it a lot but it's not designed for fast/efficient scraping of web pages.

Additionally, using fixed waits such `time.sleep(5)` will always wait 5 seconds. Consider

- If the page takes 10 seconds you'll fail
- if the page takes 1 second you're wasting 4 seconds.
- Those potential 10,000 pages * 5 seconds will be a minimum time of 50,000 seconds before any script time is taking into account.

For any synchronisation purposes have a look at explicit and implicit waits in selenium's waiting strategy [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

I would suggest you look into the `python-requests` library - see [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I've used it in success in the past, it's easy to use and it will remove chrome from the equation. You'll work at your network speed without waits. If you look for python-requests as a tag on stack overflow you'll file lots of useful code samples.

A key reason for using this library is you can access the paged data through the network layer.

A quick masterclass for you on how to see what to build:

1. Go to your page in chrome
2. Open devtools (f12)
3. Select the network tab
4. See the buttons in the top left corner - ensure recording is turned on:

[image: dev tools record]

5. Back to page and select one of the numbered tabs.

You'll see these messages appear.
[image: devtools messages]

The headers tab show you you're doing a `POST` to `https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/Chome/pagingpencarian`

The payload tab show you the data you're sending. It's really simple data - i picked page 2, and it's sending page 2 - **this will be what you can increment with a loop**:

[image: devtools post data]

Finally the response tab is what python-requests will return to you on your post.  Rip the links (or whatever you need) out of this:
[image: devtools response data]

That post and response combo on my network in the UK took 491ms. That's 4,910 seconds - which is still quite long.

I know you said 10,000 pages just as a crazy example - if you deem this script still takes too long have a google on how to [run your tests in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733763/how-to-run-pytest-tests-in-parallel).