# How can I optimize my test cases in pytest when I have to wait for 20 minutes for the results

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-html

> *I apologize if am not clear, kindly let me know I would be glad to provide more information*

In my test cases, after executing the test steps, I have to wait for 20 minutes for the results, as the **results come after 20 minutes only**.

In my automation framework, currently after executing the steps I'm waiting for 20 minutes and then validate the results, but this is leading to a lengthy execution time. I have 70 tests and each test takes around 24 minutes.

I have created my automation framework using selenium + python and pytest, and below is a skeleton of my test case

```
def test_case():
    test_steps_execution
    wait_for_20_minutes
    validate_results
```

What I have thought is that I would create a fixture that would be executed once all the test_cases are executed and in this fixture I will first wait for 20 minutes and then validate the results. However in this way the reporting would not be accurate and relevant, as in the reports the pass/failure is determined by the successful execution of the test methods or the test cases. The validations defined in the fixture would not help to mark the test case as pass or fail.

What I'm trying to achieve is to reduce the execution time of all the test cases (currently its taking 70*24 = 1680 minutes = 28 hours).

Apparently, I would like to first execute all the test cases, then wait for the results, then validate the results, and mark the tests as pass or fail based on the validations.

Comment: How about running the [tests in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733763/how-to-run-pytest-tests-in-parallel)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @tzane, however I'm already running 4 tests in parallelly, still it takes a huge amount of time. Ideally, we would want to execute the test cases in automation faster than executing them manually

Answer (score 0):

I would first use fixture to mock the results as unit tests.
These unit tests are used to validate the logic of the executions.

Then, I would use `@pytest.mark.slow` to mark the slow tests and only run them during integration testing.

I also found some tips that others curated to speed up pytest: https://github.com/zupo/awesome-pytest-speedup.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I do not want to speed up pytest or run the slow tests in the integration.

The wait time in my tests is mandatory and these tests are critical so I will have to execute them everytime. My concern is how do I optimize my tests,  most likely I will have to restructure them using the utilities provided by pytest which am not aware of